# Getting the Video Thumbnail from video taking time and tableview scroll stucking when making new frames from video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, video-thumbnails

I am trying to get thumbnail from video , table view scrolling stucking on generating the image from video when tableview is reusing the cells What I have tried so far with this code

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


                            UIActivityIndicatorView *indicatorG = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

                            dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [indicatorG removeFromSuperview];
                                [indicatorG startAnimating];
                                [indicatorG setCenter:Cell.thumbnail.center];
                                [Cell.thumbnail addSubview:indicatorG];
                            });

                            AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
                            AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
                            generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
                            float getDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
                            CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,1);

                            AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){

                                if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {

                                    NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);

                                }
                                else{

                                    UIImageView *imgV;

                                         imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im]];


                                    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                                            [indicatorG stopAnimating];
                                            Cell.thumbnail.image = imgV.image;

                                    });
                                }
                                //        [button setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            };

                            CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
                            generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
                            [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];

                        });
```

but the problem of tableview scrolling is solved using dispatch async, the new problem is the order of the thumbnail images is disturbed with this code, someone please help?

**Edit**:

Url code:

```
 NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];  
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
```

Comment: Let the block retain the indexPath of the cell. That way your order won't get messed up.

Comment: @Mercurial I am new to iOS , can u give detail explanation about it?

Comment: your url is different for each table row?

Comment: Yes my url is different for each but the call to the completion block is delayed everytime so I think whatever the image is generated first it pasting the image according to the user scrolls the page.

Comment: how are you passing the url into this code , can you show that part of code?

Comment: please check the edit.

Comment: I have same problem ? Anyone Can tell the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is running in cellForItemAtIndexPath continuously while scrolling the table view, this is not a good implementation. Call for generating the image from video in cellForItemAtIndexPath is pretty costly.

Instead of preparing thumbnails in cellForItemAtIndexPath, prepare and store thumbnails before load data to the table view. Or at least store thumbnails at somewhere once is processed in cellForItemAtIndexPath while scrolling for reuse. Than use stored thumbnails next time in cellForItemAtIndexPath and always update cell's image.

Comment: Idea is nice, I thought about doing it the same way but the problem is that each thumbnail takes 1 second to generate depending on the internet connectivity, I have tried implemented that also but what if the tableview has too many video posts and it will take so many seconds I got the idea that implementing the thumbnails is not good idea in cellforrowatindexpath but still if we generate the thumbnails async in the background thread simultaneously, it will take only few seconds to generate many number of thumbnails.